# A simple estimation

Tags: normed-spaces

Let's say $X$ is a normed linear space, and $X^*$ is its dual space.

One can define the norm in $X$ in such a way

$$
\|x\| = \sup\{|\phi(x)|:\phi \in X^*,\|\phi\|\le 1\}.
$$

The direction
$$
\|x\| \ge \sup\{|\phi(x)|:\phi \in X^*,\|\phi\|\le 1\}
$$
is obvious.
How about the other direction?

Sol:

apply Hahn-Banach thm, there exists a functional $\psi:x\mapsto \|x\|$ with $\|\psi\| = 1$.

$$
\psi(x) = \|x\|\le \sup\{|\phi(x)|:\phi \in X^*,\|\phi\|\le 1\}.
$$

Hence equality is achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the Hahn-Banach theorem.